Continuous infinitve

I'm heading over to play with her

I'm heading over to be playing with her


Is 2 wrong because there's no need to add " to be + ing"? Can you think of any examples with present continuous where using that structure "to be + ing" is justified and sound natural?

I went to play

I was going to play

I went to be playing


What about 3, 4 and 5. Do 4 and 5 have the same meaning but just different structures are used?

Water droplets must fall from the sky for it to be raining.  2 and 5 are completely wrong. It is starting to be rainy. could conceivably work.

We don't use the continuous tense (it is raining, I am walking) when we speak of an action starting or finishing. However, we can say It started raining, I started walking where raining is a participle, not part of the continuous tense.

What about now? I changed my examples.

No, one, two and five are wrong. And please do not change the question before you have answers. It messes up comments and answers.

What's wrong with one?

Dary, I used an example with another verb (walking) on purpose to show you that it doesn't matter what the verb is.

But still. I don't think 1 is incorrect.

"Can you think of any examples with present continuous [infinitives] where using that structure...is justified and sounds natural?" Try these: Alice hopes to be sleeping soundly by 11; Bob wanted to have been relaxing on vacation, but had gotten an unexpected call from work; This is no time to be playing cards: the geography exam is today!

The second example even uses the perfect continuous infinitive :)

I'm not sure your example #1 is actually wrong, but it doesn't sound natural. Something similar like "I'm heading over to go play with her" could sound fine (though informal, but that seems to fit the context), but as-is, the sentence seems stilted somehow. Maybe because it seems like the infinitive shouldn't be used as the direct object of the verb "heading"? When you add the adverb "over," it fixes the problem because "heading" ceases to be transitive (it becomes part of the phrasal verb "heading over"), so the infinitive is no longer its direct object.

Can you elaborate on 2 and 5?

@Dary Who do you mean, me or Lambie? If you're commenting to a specific user, it's helpful if you add an @-notification (like I did with your username in this comment), otherwise they won't be notified.

Anyone will do haha.

The issue with 2 and 5 is that when an infinitive is used to express purpose after a verb of motion, it should be in the simple, not the continuous, form. The infinitive in these cases, such as you used in your sentence 3 ("I went to play," which is perfectly correct) expresses the purpose for which the action of the main verb (here, "went") was done. So, the non-finite form should be one which expresses the plain concept of the verb's meaning. "To play" denotes the idea of playing; "to be playing" specifically connotes an extended time frame (thus the continuous aspect).

So: Carol went there to eat dinner is correct: "to eat" is simple aspect and expresses purpose; Carol went there to be eating dinner is incorrect: "to be eating" cannot express purpose after "went" because it is not the simple 'conceptual' form.

If you're looking for a contrary example (where only the continuous infinitive is correct, while the simple form would be wrong), consider Dan had planned to be reading the paper right now, but was interrupted by the doorbell. The continuous aspect shows that the action of 'reading the paper' was intended to span a time interval including the present ('now'), had it not been interrupted. (Note that 'planned' is not a verb of motion, and 'to be reading' is the direct object instead of an adverbial phrase expressing purpose!)

Or The guests had all planned to be hiding when Max walked in, but the surprise was thwarted by his arriving fifteen minutes early.

So are these examples correct?  1" I decided to be working while she was away"  how is it different in comparison to "I decided to work while she was away"

What about present continuous and for instance "I'm planning to be working and i'm planning to work"?

@Quack E. Duck  m
